# Make seconds update automatically?

Tags: javascript, html, time, web

I'm trying to just display the date and time on this website, and right now you have to refresh the page in order for it (the seconds, etc.) to update.  How do I make the seconds update automatically?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>JavaScript Testbed</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            Javascript will find out the date and the browser.
        </h1>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var currentTime = new Date();
            var hours = currentTime.getHours();
            var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
            var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
            var suffix = "AM";

            if (seconds < 10)
                seconds = "0" + seconds; 

            if (minutes < 10)
                minutes = "0" + minutes;

            if (hours >= 12) {
                suffix = "PM";
                hours = hours - 12;
            }
            if (hours == 0) {
                hours = 12;
            }

            document.write("<b><div id='d1'>" + hours + ":" + 
                minutes + ":"+ seconds + " " + suffix + "</div></b>");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `setInterval` to invoke handler periodically...

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your update logic in a function, and invoke it every 1000ms :)

```
function updateTime() {
  var currentTime = new Date();
  var hours = currentTime.getHours();
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
  var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
  var suffix = "AM";

  if (seconds < 10)
      seconds = "0" + seconds; 

  if (minutes < 10)
      minutes = "0" + minutes;

  if (hours >= 12) {
      suffix = "PM";
      hours = hours - 12;
  }
  if (hours == 0) {
      hours = 12;
  }

  document.write("<b><div id='d1'>" + hours + ":" + 
      minutes + ":"+ seconds + " " + suffix + "</div></b>");
}

window.setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<span class="clock"></span>
```

Javascript

```
jQuery(function($) {
  setInterval(function() {
    var date = new Date(),
        time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
    $(".clock").html(time);
  }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on my site.  using the setInterval function

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    set_time()
    window.setInterval(function(){set_time()}, 1000)

});


function set_time(){

    time = $('#time')
    raw_time = new Date();
    real_time = raw_time.getFullYear() + "-" + (raw_time.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + raw_time.getDate() + " " +  (raw_time.getHours()-12) + ":" + raw_time.getMinutes() + ":" + raw_time.getSeconds();
    time.html(real_time)
}
```

Comment: if you dont want to use jquery you would just use document.getElementById instead of $('#')

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout`, [here is a neat little script](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock) that does exactly what you want

Answer (score 0):

Using pure javascript and a updating `<span>` element

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var currentTime = new Date();
  var hours = currentTime.getHours();
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
  var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
  var suffix = "AM";

  if (seconds < 10)
    seconds = "0" + seconds;

  if (minutes < 10)
    minutes = "0" + minutes;

  if (hours >= 12) {
    suffix = "PM";
    hours = hours - 12;
  }
  if (hours == 0) {
    hours = 12;
  }

  document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = "<b><div id='d1'>" + hours + ":" +
    minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + suffix + "</div></b>";
}, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="clock"></span>
```